# Deleting query isn't working php

Tags: php, mysql

First of of all thank you all so much for this great website.

I'm in my last year in my college, and I'm working on a web-site for my school.
I've this issue for awhile and I couldn't be able to fix it, I would be thankful if you guy help me,

First, when the Admin login and go to Delete.php tap (he/she) will have drop-list to choose which page to go to and click submit button to show all data in that page, and there is checkbox to select next to all job listed, so t they choose any job they want to delete, and click the delete button, to delete specified job.

My code works till when the user choose and display all data from many tables, but it won't delete..

there are THREE FUNCTIONS, `SelectOption()`, `DisplayOption()`, `DeleteOption()`, the issue specifically is how to to add the chosen table to delete query ..

Because If you put a table name and choose it from drop list it will work.. but I want it to be optional by the user.

This is my code:

```
<?php
include('../CIEcon.php');

$GLOBALS['$table']="";

function DisplayOption(){
    include('../CIEcon.php');

echo '
            <form action= "Delete.php"  method = "post">
            <table width ="40%" cellpadding ="4" border="1" align="center" >

            <tr >
            <th style ="color: white; background-color: #f26822 ; " >     Select a Catagory To Delete From   </th>

            </tr>';


                echo "<tr>


             <td>". 

            "<select name = lists >
              <option name= nothing value= 0 selected >Choose a Catagory</option>
              <option name= nothing value= 1>    Advertising     </option>
              <option name= nothing value= 2>    Fiscal          </option>
              <option name= nothing value= 3>    Food            </option>
              <option name= nothing value= 4>    Shopping        </option>
              <option name= nothing value= 5>    Rentals         </option>
              <option name= nothing value= 6>   Setting up       </option>
              <option name= nothing value= 7>    Performances    </option>
              <option name= nothing value= 8>  Registration/Ushering  </option>
              <option name= nothing value= 9>   Master of Ceremonies  </option>
              <option name= nothing value= 10>    Cleaning up   </option>
              <option name= nothing value= 11>    Others        </option>

             </select>"



              ." </td>


             </tr>";




             echo '

             </table>
             <br/>

             <div align="center">
             <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
             <input type="reset" value="Clear" />
             <hr> <hr> 
             </div>


             </form>

             ';

///
};



function SelectOption(){
    include('../CIEcon.php');

///
             if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

                        if(isset($_POST['submit']))  // second submit
                        {
                          $errorMessage = "";

                           if(($_POST['lists'])== 0)  // trying to get error if user don't choose.
                              {
                                $errorMessage .= "<li>You Forgot to Choose !</li>";

                              }

                              $lists = $_POST['lists']; // <-save info in variable based on user input 

                              if(!empty($errorMessage)) 
                              {
                                echo("<p>There was an error with your form:</p>\n");
                                echo("<ul>" . $errorMessage . "</ul>\n");
                                die();
                              } 

                            } // end of second submit 




                            switch($lists)
                            {
                                case '1':
                                   $GLOBALS['$table']  ="Advertising";
                                break;
                                case '2':
                                  $GLOBALS['$table'] ="Fiscal";
                                break;
                                case '3':
                                    $GLOBALS['$table']="Food";
                                break;
                                case '4':
                                   $GLOBALS['$table'] ="Shopping";
                                break;
                                case '5':
                                    $GLOBALS['$table'] ="Rentals";
                                break;
                                case '6':
                                    $GLOBALS['$table'] ="SettingUp";
                                break;
                                case '7':
                                   $GLOBALS['$table'] ="Performances";
                                break;
                                case '8':
                                    $GLOBALS['$table'] ="Registration";
                                break;
                                case '9':
                                    $GLOBALS['$table'] ="MasterOfCeremonies";
                                break;
                                 case '10':
                                    $GLOBALS['$table'] ="Cleaning";
                                break;
                                 case '11':
                                    $GLOBALS['$table']="Others";
                                break;

                                default;
                                    echo 'Unsupported category';
                                break;
                            }
                if ($GLOBALS['$table'] != ""){




                            $sql = "SELECT * FROM ". $GLOBALS['$table']. "  ";

                             $result = mysqli_query($dbCIE, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($dbCIE));



                  /// NOW DISPLAY ALL INFO FROM CHOSEN DATABASE...///
                            echo "
                            <form action= 'Delete.php'  method = 'post'>
                            <table cellpadding ='4' border='1' width='80%' align='center'>
                            <tr>

                            <th>Check </th>
                            <th>Job's Name</th>
                            <th>Description</th>
                            <th> No Students needed</th>
                            <th>Due Date</th>
                            </tr>";

                            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                            {
                                echo "<br>";
                            echo "<tr>";
                            echo "<td> <input type='checkbox'  name='Id[]'  value='". $row['Id'] ."' /> </td>";
                            echo "<td>" . $row['JobName'] . "</td>";
                            echo "<td>" . $row['Description'] . "</td>";
                            echo "<td>" . $row['NoStudent'] . "</td>";
                            echo "<td>" . $row['DueDate'] . "</td>";
                            echo "</tr>";


                            }
                            echo "</table>";
                   /// END THE SEARCH HERE...........///

                            echo " <br>
                                <div align='center'>
                                <input type='reset' value='clear' > 

                                <input type='submit' name='delete' value='delete'>

                                </div>

                            </form>";

                            }  // End if !table=""; 


                          mysqli_close($dbCIE);
//                        
            } else {  }

///
};// end of function SelectOption


function DeleteOption(){

include('../CIEcon.php');



$tbl =  $GLOBALS['$table'] ; 
echo $tbl ."   beggning of function" ; 


if(isset($_POST['delete'])) {


        if( empty($_POST['Id'])   || $_POST['Id'] == 0 ){
                    echo"<h4>  please choose something to delete   </h4>";
                }else{
                                    echo "test 1: pass ";



                   $impid = implode("' , '" ,  $_POST['Id']);
                   echo  $GLOBALS['$table']."before SQL QUERY"  ;

                 $sqlDelete = "DELETE FROM ". $GLOBALS['$table']. "  WHERE Id IN ('" . $impid . "')";
                $DeleteQuery = mysqli_query($dbCIE,$sqlDelete) or die ("Error : ".mysqli_error($dbCIE));



                        }
}// end of delete... 




}; // End of Delete Function.. 



function CloseDB(){};

?>

</style>

<head><title> ..DeleteFFF.. </title></head>

DeleteFFF.php 
<body>
<!-- <a href= "../AdminIndex.php" > <button> Main Page </button></a>     -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes sir, it's optional, but it won't be defined in DeleteOption() I don't know why..

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the global variable in the DELETE query, which probably is not being set when you are doing the delete POST, pass in the table name with the POST when they click delete.

You are already using `$_POST['Id']` which you get from    `echo "<td> <input type='checkbox'  name='Id[]'  value='". $row['Id'] ."' /> </td>";`

You could just do the same thing with the table name:

```
echo "<td> <input type='checkbox'  name='Table[]'  value='". $GLOBALS['$table'] ."' /> </td>";
```

And then you can use that in your delete query with `$_POST['Table']`.

Ideally you'd strip out the use of globals everywhere (they are a bad idea generally), but this is the quickest solution.

Comment: but won't that disable the drop list that I made earlier for the user to choose table from ?

Comment: Would what disable the drop list? Adding an extra echo statement, and modifying the delete query? Nope it wouldnt :).

Comment: would u mind telling me where to adding the echo statement, is it inside the deleteOption function ? thank u in advance sir..

Comment: Just underneath where you put echo "<td> <input type='checkbox'  name='Id[]'  value='". $row['Id'] ."' /> </td>"; And actually, not sure why it is a checkbox, this should probably be type ="hidden"

Comment: Just try running a debugger, or var_dump() or echo out all the variables at each step in the code until you find something you didn't expect.

Comment: the whole issue is the scope of the variable $table, cause when I add Table name to my delete query , and choose it  from the droplist, it deletes fine.
I tried to print the $table inside the Delete function() it works ok, but after clicking the button delete, it get lost, don't know why